# Sudden errors on Google Map: TypeError: _.x is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a little Google Map with a few markers here: http://www.magicbad.com/kontakt/fachbetrieb-karte/

Since today (or maybe yesterday) there are suddenly errors popping up in the console, that I can't explain. The maps loads, but after a few seconds the errors pop up and you can't drag it anymore.

The code I use to initialize the map is (There is a little more to it with filters etc., but the errors pop up even when I switch off everything else):

```
google.load("maps", "3",  {other_params:"sensor=false"});

function initialize() {
    if($('.main.fullWidth').length > 0) var scroll = true;
    else var scroll = false;

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.3, 14.3);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: myZoom,
        scrollwheel: scroll,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
        }
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    initialize();
});
```

The errors start of with: (few seconds after you load the page)

```
Uncaught TypeError: _.x is not a function / stats.js:9
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Db' of undefined / common.js:216
Uncaught TypeError: a.set is not a function / js?v=3&sensor=false:38
```

And after that if you move your mouse over the map you get constant:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'. / common.js:31
```

Any ideas? The code might be messy, but this map has been up and running for years, why the sudden change?

Thank you for your help,

Florian

Comment: There is a syntax error in the posted code `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`, if I fix that (and define `myZoom`) [it works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/pgzftwnk/1/)

Comment: Made that error when copy pasting the code here, the error is not there on the original page. The code worked for me, too, for a few years to be precise, but it stopped working overnight and throws errors without anybody working on the site. But seems to be a rather uncommon error since nobody knows anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I found the problem. I used an old form of including the Google Maps Api script. When I switch that to exactly this:

```
  <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
  </script>
```

As mentioned in the GM basic tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial it starts working again.

So if you run across any errors of this type, first check if you API inclusion is up to date.

Comment: Thanks for this. I omitted the callback as it generated lots of errors.